# How do I have two embeds In one? discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I have a help command that sends you a list of commands on your DM's. After it's sent, I want it to send another embed in the same @bot or @client.command so.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import etc etc etc
```

@client.command()
async def help(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):

```
embed=discord.Embed(title='Commands:',colour = discord.Colour.orange())

embed.add_field(name='Bomb', value=f'Deletes Messages in chat\n .bomb 100', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Luck', value=f'Like 8ball fourtune teller', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Tof', value=f'True or False', inline=False)

embed.add_field(name='Hitme', value=f'See me holy face', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Monkey', value=f'Random pic of monkey monkey', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Whois', value=f'Userinfo', inline=False)

embed.add_field(name='coin', value=f'Flips a coin', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Dice', value=f'Random number from 1 to 6', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Randomnumber', value=f'Gives you a random number from 1 to 100', inline=False)

embed.add_field(name='Meme', value=f'Random meme?', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Say', value=f'Says what ever you want the bot to say', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Kick', value=f'Kicks user (Needs Admin)', inline=False)

embed.add_field(name='Ban', value=f'Bans user (Needs Admin', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Unban', value=f'Revokes ban from user. (Needs Admin)', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Prefix', value=f'Changes prefix e.g .prefix !', inline=False)

em.set_author(name='***Commands list has been sent!***')
em.set_footer(name='Check Your DM's! ✅')

await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

await ctx.send(embed=em)

#I want this to work so it would send this embed after it sent the embed on DM's to the channel 
  #where .help was used. this was my attempt I'm new to python
```

Comment: any errors on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer to this is to just make 2 embeds.

```py
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Sample Embed", url="https://realdrewdata.medium.com/", description="This is an embed that will show how to build an embed and the different components", color=discord.Color.blue())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
@client.command()
async def embed2(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Sample Embed", url="https://realdrewdata.medium.com/", description="This is an embed that will show how to build an embed and the different components", color=discord.Color.blue())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Or, **THIS IS UNTESTED**, try to put a url on another field:

```
embed.add_field(name="Field 1 Title", value="This is the value for field 1. This is NOT an inline field.", inline=False, url="foo")
```

The first one guaranteed works.

Answer (score 5):

Three things:

1. **em** was never defined
2. **em.set_footer** has no object `name` - its `text="Check Your DM's! ✅"`
3. **ctx.author.send** will send the embed to the author of the message -> **member.send** will send the embed to a certain user

Your code should look like:

```py
@client.command()
async def help(ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
    embed=discord.Embed(title='Commands:',colour = discord.Colour.orange())
    ...

    em = discord.Embed(title="YOU NEED TO SET A TITLE")
    em.set_author(name='***Commands list has been sent!***')
    em.set_footer(text="Check Your DM's! ✅")

    await member.send(embed=embed)

    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Why do you use `member:discord.Member = None`? You do nothing with it?

If you want to check if a member is given use:

```py
if member is None:
   await ctx.send("Please give me a user °_°")
else:
   YOUR CODE...
```

Comment: Oh no I fixed it I just can't delete this post. Idiotic of me I didn't get enough sleep that day

Comment: And discord.Member is for something else i did not mention.